# SocketIO websocket handshake is different from what is described by RFC 6455

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am attempting to learn more about the websockets protocol. According to RFC 6455, the step of this protocol is the handshake, which begins with the HTTP Upgrade request:

```
 GET /chat HTTP/1.1
    Host: server.example.com
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
    Origin: http://example.com
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
    Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

to which the server responds with a HTTP Switching Protocols message:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
    Upgrade: websocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
    Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

I attempted to observe this using a simple program based on socketIO (nodeJS websockets library. After capturing the traffic, I noticed that the first message the client sends the server is:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1443149751115-0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Origin: null
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

to which the server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 101
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Set-Cookie: io=3Z_TCqv9LKKXcWCjAAAD
Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 02:55:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

....0{"sid":"3Z_TCqv9LKKXcWCjAAAD","upgrades":    ["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
```

is SocketIO not following the RFC for websockets or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

socket.io has it's own connection management stuff BEFORE it connects on a webSocket that allows it to negotiate which type of connection it's actually going to make to the server and allows it to send some configuration options down to the client.  This will confuse you if you're trying to study a plain webSocket.

socket.io is an additonal protocol on top of webSocket.  It will eventually use a standard webSocket underneath, but it will have additional stuff around that.  If you continued to follow the socket.io connection, you would have eventually seen a standard webSocket connection.

I would suggest you first just make a plain webSocket connection from your client (no socket.io) and study that network trace.

Comment: Are these differences documented anywhere?

Comment: @SivaDotRender - It is documented and there are many implementations of socket.io in other languages besides just what the original implementors wrote themselves.  I'm not sure where the best doc is, but there is some [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol) and [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol).

Answer (score 4):

In js client side, connect to server with websocket transports. That enables default websocket mechanism as the same as RFC 6455.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {
   transports: [
     'websocket',
     'polling'
   ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what im looking for !

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct, socket.io does not respect RFC 6455.  To test this I ran a javascript server in an ubuntu virtualbox, and in the host ubuntu performed a successful socket.io interaction with the server.  I captured the network traffic with `sudo tcpdump -i vboxnet1  -w dump.out` and analyzed the results with wireshark.

The socket.io handshake is just as the original poster represents, and the entire script completes successfully (with client receiving websocket messages) without the `tcpdump` ever displaying an HTTP request with an upgrade header as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1